# powershell if statement not executing

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am trying to write a Powershell script to automate AD user creation. We are a mixed Linux/Windows environment and use a text (now CSV) file to keep track of old linux UID #'s and usernames so they don't accidentally get re-used. I'm trying to get my script to parse the file but I can't seem to get the comparison to work.

```
$sam = $GivenName.substring(0,1).ToLower() + $lastname.ToLower()
$usernames=Import-csv "uid.csv" 
ForEach($users in $usernames){
if($usernames.username -contains $sam){$uid = $true}
}
```

I've used several different ways that I've found from around the web to read the data into an array from the file but the problem seems to be that no matter what, it never sets $uid = $true and I have no idea why.

Edit:
I changed the if statement to this:

```
if($users.username -contains $sam){$uid = $true}
```

and it worked. Thanks for the help!

To clear up some confusion, the $GivenName and $lastname are input by the user and I am only looking for an exact match since I'm trying to avoid re-used usernames. Also, changing the -contains to -eq works as well. I've been fighting this for WAY too long and if you couldn't tell I'm a bit of a Powershell noob.

Comment: Where do `$GivenName` and `$lastname` come from? That is, are you confident in the value of `$sam` being correct? Is this part of a larger script (an inner loop) which is looping through a collection of users you've derived from another source?

Comment: Is the value stored in the username column an exact match for `$sam` or a partial match?

Comment: Please post the first few lines of **uid.csv**, including the header row. Also, how are you assigning **$givenname** and **$lastname**? Please show any relevant code, and provide examples of data sources so we can see what they look like.

Comment: If you are doing `foreach($users in $usernames)` you should be using `$users` in the code block, not `$usernames`

Comment: Changing the $usernames.username to $users.username fixed it. More comments in the main question. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear from the information you've provided, but here's what I think is the problem: Since **$usernames** comes from a CSV file, the **$usernames.username** is a string. The **-contains** operator is used on collections (such as arrays), and will only work if there's an exact match (and if you're looking for exact matches, you should use **-eq**, but I'm assuming that's not what you want). Use **-match** instead. Also, you're setting **$users** to each record in the CSV, so it should be **$users.username**. Change the **if** statement to this:

```
if ($users.username -match $sam) {
  $uid = $true
}
```

Comment: Changing the $usernames.username to $users.username fixed it. More comments in the main question. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The looping variable that you are using in your loop in `$users`, but within the loop you use `$usernames`. You probably wanted to use `$users.username` within the if statement

Comment: I didn't even notice that, but yeah, that's also part of the problem. But also, **-contains** won't work unless it's an exact match, and I assume that's not what he's expecting, otherwise he'd have used **-eq**.

Comment: Changing the $usernames.username to $users.username fixed it. More comments in the main question. Thanks!!!